# Create list of previous lists in a dict values

Tags: python

I have a dictionary in which the values are lists. I need to create a list of these lists in the dictionary

My dict (which is the input)

```
input = [
    {
        'key': 'list1',
        'values': [4,5,2,3,4,5,2,3],
     }
    ,{
        'key': 'list2',
        'values': [1,1,34,12,40,3,9,7],
    }
]
```

The output I need:

```
[[4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3], [1, 1, 34, 12, 40, 3, 9, 7]]
```

I've tried to write a code, but the output is wrong. The code I wrote:

```
lista_master = []

def compute_deviation(list_numbers):
    for dic in list_numbers:
      lista = list(dic.values())[1]
      lista_master.append(lista)
      print(lista_master)
```

The wrong output from my code:

```
[[4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3]]
[[4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3], [1, 1, 34, 12, 40, 3, 9, 7]]
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: `[x['values'] for x in list_numbers]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the value of `lista_master` every iteration of the loop, so a total 2 times in your case, you just need to move it outside the loop like so:

```
def compute_deviation(list_numbers):
    lista_master = [] # I also moved the "lista_master" inside the function
    for dic in list_numbers:
      lista = list(dic.values())[1]
      lista_master.append(lista)
    print(lista_master) #<--- here is the change
```

now:

```
compute_deviation(input)
```

output:

```
[[4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3], [1, 1, 34, 12, 40, 3, 9, 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple list comprehension will deliver the result you're looking for.

```
data = [
  {
    'key':    'list1',
    'values': [4,5,2,3,4,5,2,3],
  },
  {
    'key':    'list2',
    'values': [1,1,34,12,40,3,9,7],
  }
]

result = [d['values'] for d in data]
```

Converting the values of a dictionary to a list and then retrieving based on an index in that list is pointless and fragile vs. just using a normal dictionary lookup.

When I talk about fragility, consider:

```
>>> a = [{'b': 42, 'c': 67}, {'c': 58, 'b': 17}]
>>> a
[{'b': 42, 'c': 67}, {'c': 58, 'b': 17}]
>>> d = []
>>> for e in a:
...     v = list(e.values())
...     d.append(v[1])
... 
>>> d
[67, 17]
>>> [d['c'] for d in a]
[67, 58]
>>>
```

When I use a numeric index to get the second value in each dictionary, I don't necessarily get the value at index `'c'`.

When I use the normal dictionary lookup, I do, regardless of the order of the key/value pairs in the dictionary.